# The App Source is displayed upto WebView, so I am unable to inspect the elements on the Android build through Appium Inspector

Tags: android, ionic-framework

The App Source is displayed upto WebView, so I am unable to inspect the elements on the Android build through Appium Inspector, but I'm able to inspect the iOS build. Developed on the Ionic 6 framework.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q772v.png)

How to Resolve the inspect issue.